# Winning strategy for removing coins from coin piles of size 2020 and 2021

Tags: probability, combinatorial-game-theory

Suppose that two players A and B are playing a game on two piles of coins of size 2020 and 2021. 
There are two actions available:

1. Remove one coin from each pile.
2. Remove two coins from any one pile.

The player who removes the last coin wins.

Suppose A goes first. Who has a winning strategy?

Comment: When you are down to one pile with one coin, is there a legal move? And as for the question itself, note that both of the legal moves keep the sum of the piles at the same parity (even/odd). Can you use this?

Comment: No matter what either player does, the total number of coins decreases by $2$ with each move, so after each player has made $1010$ moves, it'll be the first player's "turn" again but there will be just one coin remaining. The rules don't allow that last coin to be removed, so neither player wins.

Comment: If we make believe "The player who removes the last coin wins" actually says "The last player who removes a coin wins", then we get a winner (using the ideas in the previous comments).